# Getting row index of QTableWidget by clicking vertical header?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget containing the output of various math functions. The user needs to be able to click the number next to a row (the vertical header) and I need to get the index of the row that was clicked. I've been searching for a while but I can't find exactly what I need. I've read something about using the verticalHeader() sectionDoubleClicked() signal but I can't get this working. Normally I'd just right click the widget in the designer and go to the slot I wanted but it isn't there.

I've tried

```
QObject::connect(ui->table->verticalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionDoubleClicked(int)),this,SLOT(termSelect(int)));
```

where termSelect is

```
void termSelect(int index)
{
    cout << "row selected: " << index;
}
```

but I get a no such slot error.

I tried doing this in the header file

```
public Q_SLOTS:
    void cTermSelect(int);
```

but then I get a linking error.

I feel like I'm making a horribly butchered mess of this and that there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Did you forget to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class definition?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `sectionDoubleClicked` signal is triggered on *double click*, while your question is about single click. You can use `sectionClicked` signal as well if you like.

Your slot declaration is `cTermSelect` but you refer to it in the code you use `termSelect`. Probably this is the cause of the issue. The rest of the code is fine.

When user clicks a vertical header, the clicked row is selected and becomes current by default. I hope that you don't want to do something surprisingly different on header click because it would ruin user experience. So tracking table selection should be enough. You can use `QTableWidget`'s `itemSelectionChanged` or `currentCellChanged` signal to detect it.